# AJAX jQuery - update content every full minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, time

I'm thinking on a clock that will refresh every full minute if system clock on users computer will look like this eg. 11:08:00, it'll refresh and 11:09:00 etc.

I've tryed to `setInterval()`:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../time.php",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(result){
            $('.time').html(result);
        }
    })
}, 60000);
```

But it's reloading every minute after page load.

Is there any solution?

Comment: @Lorenzo No, that'd be 6 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var interval    =   0;
function start(){
    setTimeout( function(){
        ajax_function();
        interval    =   60;
        setInterval( function(){
            ajax_function();
        }, interval * 1000);
    }, interval * 1000);    
}

function ajax_function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../time.php",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(result){
            $('.time').html(result);
        }
    }); 
}

$( window ).load(function(){
    var time    =   new Date();
    interval    =   60 - time.getSeconds();
    if(interval==60)
        interval    =   0;
    start();
});
```

Comment: this is what i've searching for dude you're great

Answer (score 4):

`setInterval()` won't invoke its function immediately, the first time the function runs in this case will be 60 seconds after page load. You can make the following changes to get the result you're looking for:

- Place your AJAX request in a function
- Call the function as soon as the page loads
- Use `setTimeout()` in the success function of `.ajax()`, rather than `setInterval()` around the whole thing. If there is an error with the request, `setInterval()` will carry on regardless, but `setTimeout()` won't go again until the request is successful.
- Split the result, taking the seconds away, and if the result is different to what is already in `.time`, change it. This assumes that `result` is a string like `11:08:00`
- If you want to acknowledge when the server returns a time where the minute has changed, you need to check it **every second**

```
function update(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../time.php",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(result){
            var secondless = result.split(':'), $time = $('.time');
            secondless = secondless [0]+':'+secondless [1];
            $time.html(function(_,v){
                return secondless != v ? secondless : v
            }
            setTimeout(update, 1000);
        }
    })
}
update();
```

Comment: That's still every 60 seconds from page load, not on the minute change. You're also potentially going to get errors introduced by the time the AJAX request takes to return a response.

Comment: I completely misunderstood - Weird how I understood better with the two lines that you wrote rather than the whole description in the actual question. Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Edit made.

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getSeconds(); 
while(n != 0){
    d = new Date();
    n = d.getSeconds(); 
    if(n == 0){
         setInterval(function(){
           $.ajax({
               url: "../time.php",
               context: document.body,
               success: function(result){
                    $('.time').html(result);
                }
             })
         }, 60000);
    }
}
```

Comment: The ajax will be called only when the system get a full minute. Something like:
when time is 10:10:59 it wont start
when time is 10:11:00 it will start and every full minute will be called

Comment: `setTimeout(update, 60000);` what is it? and where? or this is due to copied from another answer.

Comment: I copied the wrong ajax rsrs, I wanted to copy from question

Comment: Humm, I just show the logic to start in full minute, if setTimeout works, use setTimeout.

Comment: @Jai `setTimeout()` is the wrong function. It only executes a single time, which means that you have to initialise it again yourself. You can either do that 1. straight away (making it pointless) or 2. when the AJAX request returns (making the code wrong). If you want the request to be sent on the minute change you need a 60 second interval, you don't want 60 seconds plus whatever extra time the AJAX request actually takes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your function exactly on the minute based on the users system time, then you need to instantiate the Date time object and check the current state of getSeconds(), if it equals 0, then you are exactly on the minute, if not, you need to subtract its result from 60, then pass that to setTimeout which will invoke the setInterval function exactly on the minute.

Crude example;

```
var time = new Date();
var timeout = 0;

if ( time.getSeconds() != 0 ) {
   timeout = (60 - time.getSeconds());
}

setTimeout(function(){

    setInterval( function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "../time.php",
      context: document.body,
      success: function(result){
        $('.time').html(result);
      }
    })}, 60000);

}, timeout);
```

Alternative example for the code golfers;

```
setTimeout(function(){

    setInterval( function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "../time.php",
      context: document.body,
      success: function(result){
        $('.time').html(result);
      }
    })}, 60000);

}, (60 - new Date().getSeconds()) );
```

Answer (score 1):

user2703250 almost got it right, please see edited verison below:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getSeconds(); 
while(n !== 0){
d = new Date();
n = d.getSeconds(); 
if(n === 0){ dopage_update();}
}

function dopage_update(){
     $.ajax({
            url: "../time.php",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(result){
                  $('.time').html(result);
                  setTimeout(function(){dopage_update();}, 60000);
            }
          });
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood you correctly, you could check the clock the first time the action is run and use `seTimeout` to fire `setInterval` exactly when the clock reaches next `hh:mm:00`.