# How to refresh string in php

Tags: php, ajax

I made this code to make a multiple pages in my php

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'go_depo') {
   function loadStatus(){
    if($json->data->pending_received_balance != '0'){
    $checkaddr = $block_io->get_transactions(array('type' => 'received', 'before_tx' => '', 'addresses' => $getaddr->data->address));
    if($checkaddr->data->txs[0]->amounts_received[0]->amount){
        if($checkaddr->data->txs[0]->amounts_received[0]->amount <= $amounthyips){
            $checkadr = '<strong>Order Status:</strong> Your payment amount is less than $166. Please contact admin for more information';
        }else{
            if($checkaddr->data->txs[0]->txid){
                $checkadr = '<span class="text-success">Payment Completed</span> TXID: <a href="https://dogechain.info/tx/'.$checkaddr->data->txs[0]->txid.'" target="_blank">'.$checkaddr->data->txs[0]->txid.'</a>';
            }else{
                $checkadr = '<strong>Order Status:</strong> Waiting for payment';
            }
        }
    }else{
    $checkadr = '<strong>Order Status:</strong> Waiting for payment';
    }
    }else{
    echo 'kosong';
    }
   }
}
```

How to get the value $success change? From ajax or something? Without refreshhing the page?

So the function is to get interval refresh content and find the changed value of success string

=====================================
edit my code, i want function loadStatus update every 10 seconds by jquery or javascript function in html without page refresh

Comment: `$success` has no value.

Comment: I will post full code, wait

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX jQuery - update content every full minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777367/ajax-jquery-update-content-every-full-minute)

Comment: I think you're confused about multiple PHP script execution, your code didn't appears to make sense. If you want to share some variable between two HTTP call's to PHP scripts, you'll need to use *sessions*. Please refer to the PHP manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: This is a long wait.

Comment: I edited first post

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using javascript AJAX call's and setInterval() method, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval ( function ()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  // First, check if XMLHttpRequest exist at window object (IE 7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari
  if ( window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
  } else {
    // Otherwise, it's IE <7
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject ( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
    if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById ( 'refresh_div').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open ( 'POST', 'youscript.php?action=go_depo', true);
  xmlhttp.send ();
}, 10000);
</script>
```

Note: I'm calling **yourscript.php**, you need to change at the open() method. Also, the result of this script will be replaced at a <div> element on the page with *id=refresh_div*.

Comment: how to just load the function loadStatus() instead of yourscript.php?action=go_depo ?

Comment: You need to create a PHP script witch check for $_GET["action"] and if it contains "go_depo", call the function. The output will be printed at <div id="refresh_div">content here</div>.